# Wordpress' Page editor changed to "Block" format, and lost theme components

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Today I logged into my WordPress admin and was prompted to "Update the database," no options were given so I did. After that, my pages showed a "new" visual composer based in blocks that showed none of my theme's components, but only a text block with a series of shortcodes.

It changed the usual backend vs frontend editor that the visual composer shows and allows me to manipulate my page through rows and columns.

PAGE EDITOR NOW:

[image: Editor after update]

PAGE EDITOR BEFORE:

[image: Editor before update]

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling plugins, the theme itself, etc. But no success so far.

Is there a way to revert to the last editor (no backups), or debug why I'm only getting shortcodes?

Answer (score 4):

So as I was posting this question I logged into another one of my sites and saw an alert warning me of the automatic inclusion of "Gutenberg" (a new page editor) after version 5.0.1 of Wordpress. That was it.

According to their suggestion, I downloaded this plugin which solved my problem: https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/

Hope this helps someone!